# java.sql.SQLException: Error opening connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite

I'm trying to connect to an SQLite using MacBook Apple Silicone M1.
Here is my code to make the connection the URL is exactly the SQLite name when I create it inside IntelliJ.

Here is the code.

```
 private static final String SQLite_URL = "jdbc:sqlite:identifier.sqlite";
```

```
        Connection conn = null;
        if (DatastoreToggles.isUnderTest) {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(SQLite_URL_TEST);

                System.out.println("Connection to test SQLite successful");

            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(SQLite_URL);

                System.out.println("Connection to SQLite successful");

            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return conn;
    }
```

I already checked other people with similar problems, I did update my maven but the problem is still there.

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Test connection inside IntelliJ passes but cannot connect with my code.

Here is the report for the console
[image: the full error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M1 support is released in 3.32.3.3 of sqlite-jdbc, but you are using 3.25.2. So, please update your dependency

Comment: change the dependency and it's working thanks !

Comment: Please mark the answer as "accepted", so other users easily see it helped.